# how to customize the header in UICollectionView Swift3

Tags: swift3

I am trying to utilize the header in UICollectionView,and I want the header itself to be a collectionview as well.

in my headerView.swift class,

```
class headerView : UICollectionResuableView {
override init(frame: frame)
setupViews()

required init?(coder: aDecoder: NSCoder){
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
let headerCollectionView = UICollectionView = {
let layout =UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstrains = false
collectionView.backgroundColor =UIColor.white
return collectionView
}()

func setupViews(){
backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
addSubview(headerCollectionView)
addConstrains(...)//horizontal
addConstrains(...)//vertical


}


}
```

i have the above code written down, and after run, i found nothing has been changed.I altered the background color, it's still the same.

I also have a label in my header. It's just a simple outlet with some texts, and the label is still showing its text contents.

My intention is to have another collectionview inside my header right under the label.

I also tried to register my headerView class in my collectionview controller, but got a compilation error says the register won't invoke with the parameter i provided.

Please shine some light on me about how to get a beautiful working collectionview header make of collectionview.

Thank you and happy new year!

Comment: Your code does not comply, please fix it, and we can take a look.

Comment: wwhat do you mean does not comply? The part i gave is just for the header